# Is it possible to select a row of a table having role=grid using linktext?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

I have a table in which the rows are shuffled every time. I want to select a particular row by its text, which I'm not able to do that. If I use `xpath` or `cssSelector` I am able to select by its position but not by `name`. Can you help me out to select this?

Comment: What do you mean "row by its text"? Normally rows do not contain text, but the columns. Give us the example of your table.

Comment: It means - by the name it appears on the UI page.

Comment: I've done this by text using XPATH, but it's hard to know what this would look like for you without seeing some of the html for what you're trying to select. Can you include that in the question? I prefer css selectors, but if you have to search by text and go back up the dom xpath is the way to go.

Comment: If you want the `tr`, it might look something like this... `//tr[.//*[contains(text(),'Your text')]`. It's hard to say for sure without seeing the html or which element exactly you're trying to click.

Comment: My url is not working currently so I'm unable to send the html code and unable to test it .I will let you know if it works.Sorry for delayed response

Comment: <div class="k-grid-header">....</div> <div class="k-grid-content k-auto scrollable"> <table role="grid" datarole="selectable" class="k-selectable"> <colgroup>.....</colgroup> <tbody role="row group"> <tr data uid="6545644646" role="row" class="ng-scope"> <td class role="grid-cell">==$0 <span ng-bind="dataitem.Name" class="ng-binding">Template1</span></td> <td class role="grid cell"</td> –

Comment: this is the code and I want the row to be selected using "Template1"

Answer (score 1):

```
string mystring;
IList<IWebElement> mylist;
Thread.Sleep(2000);
//Search Table
mylist = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(Table));
if (mylist.Count >= 1)
{
    foreach (IWebElement ele in mylist)
    {
        mystring = ele.Text;
        if (mystring == "your text")
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(mystring)).Click();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Premaja IOW: Loop over all elements with your text (locate them by whatever fits), check other attributes, pick the one element which fits the bill

Comment: If the table is large, this brute force approach can be pretty expensive. Also in this case, is `ele` the element you want to click when the string matches? If so there is no need to find the element again, just call `ele.Click();` in the if statement. Looks like a workable solution as far as I can see unless you don't want the element, but the row that contains it.

Comment: <div class="k-grid-header">....</div>

Comment: <div class="k-grid-header">....</div>
<div class="k-grid-content k-auto scrollable">
<table role="grid"  datarole="selectable" class="k-selectable">
<colgroup>.....</colgroup>
<tbody role="row group">
<tr data uid="6545644646" role="row" class="ng-scope">
<td class role="grid-cell">==$0 
<span ng-bind="dataitem.Name" class="ng-binding">Template1</span></td>
<td class role="grid cell"</td>

Comment: this is the code and I want the row to be selected using "Template1"